# Safari does not support HTML5 Save functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, safari, servicestack

We have written an application using AngularJS and ServiceStack that enables download of various documents indiivdually and as zip files from the server from a AngularJS based HTML client. The AngularJS/Javascript application is able to call the server side code using a REST call, and gets the binary data and assembles a blob object on the client and triggers a client side save of the file using the HTML5 W3C saveAs(). The blob's content-type is set to application/octet-stream. This functionality works fine in Chrome, FireFox, Opera and even in IE and Edge.

However, Safari throws an exception saying **"Failed to load resource: Frame load interrupted"**. Is there a working Javscript or AngularJS example for Safari that someone can share with me which will allow me to assemble a blob of binary data streamed from the server side?

Here is the snippet of code:

```
        var arr = results.data;
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        var outputFileName = "somefilename.zip";
        saveAs(blob, outputFileName);
```

We also have tried several Javascript frameworks that try to alleviate the browser differences such as the following:

1. Download.Js (http://danml.com/download.html)
2. FileSaver.js (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/ )

Neither of them worked for Safari.

We are stuck and we need to figure out what to do regarding our Safari users. I am using Safari version 9.0.x if that helps. Any code examples that work in Safari will be deeply appreciated!

John

Comment: `FileSaver.js` doesn't use frames, so the error **must** be different when you use that to what you've reported

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please see this link for what we encountered when using FileSaver.js. [link] (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/194)